# How to use Regex to verify data input from keyboard is real numbers with C languages?

Tags: c, regex

I try to research for REGEX in C and try to understand but I have trouble with pattern of the string type.
In this program I want to verify string input is a number(only digits number, not characters, space, or special characters)

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <regex.h> 
 void print_result(int return_value){
  if (return_value == 0){
    printf("Pattern found.\n");
  }
  else if (return_value == REG_NOMATCH){
    printf("Pattern not found.\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("An error occured.\n");
  }
}
int main() {
  regex_t regex;
  int return_value;
  int return_value2;
  return_value = regcomp(&regex,"[^a-fA-F_][0-9]+",0);
  return_value = regexec(&regex, "4324", 0, NULL, 0);
  return_value2 = regcomp(&regex,"\d+",0);
  return_value = regexec(&regex, "4324", 0, NULL, 0);
  print_result(return_value);  //not found
  print_result(return_value); //no found
  print_result(return_value2);
  return 0;
}
```

Can you give me some ideas to verify the input. I want find another way without use ASCII values

Comment: You can check if a string is composed only of characters `'0'` to `'9'` without using *regex* library.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the flags as 0 in `regcomp`:

```
return_value = regcomp(&regex,"[^a-fA-F_][0-9]+",0);
```

then you are accepting the default regex syntax, which is a so-called [Basic Regular Expression (BRE)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). The only sensible thing that can be said about BREs is "don't use them." Always specify the `REG_EXTENDED` flag (at least), and then you will be working with a regular expression syntax that at least bears a passing resemblance to what you expect. (Otherwise, your strings will be dominated by what's technically called "leaning timber": `\` characters which enable metacharacters in the regex, and more `\` characters so that the `\` characters you need are not treated as escape characters in the character string.)

Take a look at [man regexec](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regexec.3.html) and [man 7 regex](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) for more details. Make sure you read the second link thoroughly (although you can ignore basic regular expression syntax :-) ) because there are many commonly-used syntaxes in more modern regex libraries which are not present in Posix regexes, not even extended ones. (That includes `\d`, used in your second regex. Posix has named character classes, such as `[[:digit:]]`.)

Comment: Can you give me some ideas to fix this

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand the intent of the negated character class `[^a-fA-F_]`

Comment: Sorry about `[^a-fA-F_]`, I sow it in StackOver and copy it to my code to try to fix this problem. I also not sure about it, we can change it to be `[^a-zA-Z] (no word)